# Blank screen after Launch.storyboard in Apple SceneKit game - really annoying bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, viewcontroller

So the main problem is a blank screen after Launch.storyboard finishes.
But from the beginning: I wanted to use fullscreen in my game. When I checked "Requires full screen" AND "Launch Screen File" was left empty like on the image, [image: image1]

... the app runs without launch screen (as expected), but I get a scene which is NOT playing as fullscreen, like on the image below, (the status bar is visible, there are also two black bars on either side). In the GameViewController I have: `override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }`,

[image]

In info.plist I have:
[image]

No matter what I do I do not get full screen without visible status bar.
Now, I change to this:

[image]

And... Launch.storyboard shows itself (it has only text, not any large pictures), after this nothing happens, there is only blank screen without any images. I can hear background music, I can even touch the screen and the game runs but I do not see anything. This happens on both my physical devices - iPhone SE 1-st and 2-nd gen. attached to my computer. Interestingly, when I press device's sound level buttons, up or down, .. voila, and I can see everything now, the game scene appears! (full screen without status bar, as I expected).
I tried everything: reinstall app, remove Xcode cache, reboot computer and device - nothing works, all the time blank screen with music. I checked on the simulators - on SE (2) and others everything works fine, the launch.storyboard loads, the game is visible from the beginning. On another physical device, iPhone 12 works fine, also on iPad Pro works fine, (but for a very short time the black screen appears). Maybe it has something with memory, but on the other hand SE 2-nd gen. is rather new device.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong and how to fix this? I do not want to publish the app until I am 100% sure that it works on all devices without any issues.

Comment: Have you tryed to make a complete fresh project (New  Project, Game, Scenekit) and then copy your existing code to the new project?

Comment: This seems to be an acceptable approach, and actually I was thinking about it. But on the other hand, there must be a cause of such behavior,  and I would like to know this cause.

Comment: I would give it a try... if it works as expected with a fresh project, you must have some bug in your original project.

Comment: It doesn't work properly with a fresh project.

Comment: can you share your project, so I can have a look at it...?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ZAY, but I think I have found the answer after many attempts. When Xcode creates the default Game scene, it creates Main.storyboard that looks like this: [image].
What I did: instead of default SceneKit View, I added default View, like this:
[image]
Everything seems to work now. Do not know why, but it works.